# Problem running our client from within Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, rmi

Whenever we run our Java client from within Eclipse to contact a server app using RMI, we get an exception:
 java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 01

This only happens from within Eclipse, nowhere else (IntelliJ, command line, etc.).

Does anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have [encountered this issue before ;)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308430) and it is [seen with JBoss too](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform.rcp/msg19181.html).

It usually is a:

- classpath problem (you need to include some j2ee libraries).
- Or your stream is used by another method.
- Or the [context class loader is not appropriately set in eclipse](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.birt/msg29321.html):
  [example below:](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.birt/msg29330.html)

> The `ClassLoader` that is in the context when the viewer is running is the `org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader`.
>
> So if I do the following:

```
ClassLoader savedClassLoader = Thread.currentThread.getContextClassLoader();
if (savedClassLoader.getClass().getName().equalsIgnoreCase("org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader")){
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(this.getClass().getClassLoader());
}
```

> and then set the saved loader back in the `IConnection.Close()`, it works

Answer (score 0):

Could it be incompatibility between server and client code?  What JVM did you use to compile each one?